# How can I extract recursively from binary structure

Tags: python, search, recursion, data-structures, graph

I have this class in Python:

```
class PointInfo(object):

    def __init__(self, pnt, vect, src1, src2, fun):

        self.point = pnt
        self.vector = vect
        self.src1 = src1
        self.src2 = src2
        self.func = fun
```

I have created a list (imp_list) that each element of this list is an object of type PointInfo, source1 or source2 can refer to some base point (which start with "Original") or they contain the index of previous element in this list which by help of that element we created this object.

Each object is built like (source1 function source2) function is some Boolean operation, now I want to trace back each point and find out where each one come from till reach the base point.

For example if I have a list like this:
[image]

If I want to trace back where point 0 came from it must give me: `(Ori1 & Ori2)`

Or where point 1 came from it must give me: `(Ori3 | (Ori1 & Ori2))`

Or where point 2 came from it must give me: `(Ori4 ^ (Ori1 & Ori2))`

Or where point 3 came from it must give me: `(Ori5 & (Ori3 | (Ori1 & Ori2)))`

And so on, how can I achieve this by help of python?

Comment: So is this a pyramid with two peaks?

Comment: @user2963623 what do you mean?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you really mean, anyway each object is combination of two other object now this two can be some base object (which start with Ori) or another object that I kept the index of that object in array for it.

Comment: Just one question: how would I know if a source is Origin?

Comment: @user2963623 as you can see in the image if the source is origin I put the string value of it in the variable otherwise it has an integer which specifies the index.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA: Do does point 1 there really have 0 (the number zero) as its source, or does it have the object `points[0]` as its source (that is, the object at index 0 in the list)?

Comment: @BrenBarn it had the index , so 0 here means the value of imp_list with index 0 which means imp_list[0] or the first element of the list

Comment: @Am1rr3zA: Do you really want it that way?  That seems fragile, because someone could change `imp_list` and get things out of sync.  Why not have each object store the actual objects that are its "sources"?

Comment: @BrenBarn actually right now it should be like this and I have some mekanism to be sure imp_list is always in sync

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of achieving it:

```
def trace_source(point):
    if str(point.src1).startswith("Ori") and str(point.src2).startswith("Ori"):
        return '('+point.src1+' '+str(point.func)+' '+point.src2+')'
    elif str(point.src1).startswith("Ori") and not str(point.src2).startswith("Ori"):
        return '('+point.src1+' '+str(point.func)+' '+trace_source(imp_list[point.src2])+')'
    elif not str(point.src1).startswith("Ori") and str(point.src2).startswith("Ori"):
        return '('+trace_source(imp_list[point.src1])+' '+str(point.func)+' '+point.src2+')'
    else:
        return '('+trace_source(imp_list[point.src1])+' '+str(point.func)+' '+trace_source(imp_list[point.src2])+')'
```

This is the basic idea. You might have to tweak the code a little bit depending on the data structure.

**EDIT**

I tested your code with the following list using your given class:

```
imp_list = []
imp_list.append(PointInfo(None, None, "Ori1", "Ori2", "&"))
imp_list.append(PointInfo(None, None, 0, "Ori3", "|"))
imp_list.append(PointInfo(None, None, 0, "Ori4", "^"))
imp_list.append(PointInfo(None, None, 1, "Ori5", "&"))
imp_list.append(PointInfo(None, None, 3, "Ori6", "&"))

for point in imp_list:
    print  trace_source(point)
```

The result was:

```
(Ori1 & Ori2)
((Ori1 & Ori2) | Ori3)
((Ori1 & Ori2) ^ Ori4)
(((Ori1 & Ori2) | Ori3) & Ori5)
((((Ori1 & Ori2) | Ori3) & Ori5) & Ori6)
```

So, apparently this will work.

Comment: Tanx it gave me some idea, but I will not accept it right now to see if I can find better solution if not I will accept it later on.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA : No problem! By the way, is this related to propositional logic?

Answer (score 0):

You simply perform depth-first search using a recursive procedure as what has been given by @user2963623. The important part of recursion is to:

1. identify the base case
2. How the parameters change through the recursive call
3. What sort of result we return to its upper level when current level finishes

In your particular case, given a point x, you continue to trace back by following the 'link' of `src1` or `src2` or both, until you reach the 'origin'

**1. The base case:**

if both `src1` and `src2` start with 'origin', return it

**2. recursively explore**

'src1' if it has a 'link' to other point

or 'src2' if it has a 'link' to other point

or 'src1' and 'src2' if both have a 'link' to other point